# Delayed while loop

Tags: java, timer, while-loop

I need a loop with delay (like a timer) but have problems with the end of it, this is my code:

```
while(true) {
    if (someValue == 10) {
        break;
    }
    //Wait two seconds. <-----
}
System.out.println("While Ended.");
```

This works fine, but need to be repeated every 2 seconds. I tried with `Timer` but the "While Ended." message is shown before of the timer end. How can i solve this problem?

- I need that this process not freeze the thread. (like while loop).
- Precision is not necessary.

Comment: You need to post a more detailed question, see the advice here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask It's not clear what you've tried, and what worked or didn't work.

Comment: It is clear, i need that example code, but with a delay of two seconds. Just that. See now my code

Comment: I'm with @HarryHarrison, and nothing is ever clear as it seems. For instance, if any delay were called from within a Swing GUI, you'd freeze the GUI rendering it useless, so if you get a request for more information, and if the answers you've received don't answer your question, you may do well to provide more key information and code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Did you read my post until the end? At the end of my post I've cleared that up. ("I need that this process not freeze the thread. (like while loop)").

Comment: Yes I read that, but I still posit that more pertinent information is better. But hopefully all is moot, as I do hope that one of the answers below have helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can put `Thread.sleep` in a while-loop to sleep for a number of seconds. This solution has problems, e.g. it blocks the thread, breaks on interrupts, etc.

Better is to use a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and use the `schedule` method to schedule the task to run every so many seconds. This is correct but you should have some knowledge of how multithreaded programs work or you'll make mistakes and create subtle bugs.

Answer (score 1):

When you need something like a timer than you could use a timer:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TTimer extends TimerTask {

    private static Timer timer; 

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("timer");
    }

    public void stop() {
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
        this.cancel();
    }

    public TTimer( long interval) {
        timer = new Timer(true);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 0, interval);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TTimer t = new TTimer(2000);
        while( true ) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Place your code in the run() method, check your condition (somevalue == 10) and call the stop method to shut the timer down.

Comment: Hi, this works but the code after of the TTimer instance are executed when the timer not finished (in my first post i said this).